# How to create a default `creationDate` for a document in sanity.io?

Tags: date, sanity

I have checked the [documentation](https://www.sanity.io/docs/schema-types/datetime-type) of how to do this, but I have not found an answer.

Basically, when a document is created/published, I want to set a `createdDate` for the document (as a read-only/hidden field).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [svale's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48816172/how-to-create-a-default-creationdate-for-a-document-in-sanity-io#comment85099833_48816422), it is possible to set both `_createdAt` and `_updatedAt` but only upon creation. I've been using [Sanity's official JS client](https://www.sanity.io/docs/js-client) and it allows me to do this:

```
await client.create({
    _type: "someType",
    _createdAt: "2019-12-31T12:34:56Z",
    _updatedAt: "2020-01-01T12:34:56Z",
});
```

Additionally, it's possible to set a custom `_id` if needed.

When updating a document, those attributes are indeed read-only and cannot be manually changed.

Answer (score 7):

I found the answer [here](https://www.sanity.io/docs/document-type).

> At its core, a document is a JSON-object that has a unique _id, timestamps (***`_createdAt`***, `_updatedAt`) and revision-marker _rev.

So the created date is generated automatically by sanity, including many other interesting properties.

Comment: Exactly. _createdAt is a read-only property locked in when the document is created. You can actually submit a _createdAt and _updatedAt value as the document is created (via the apis, in order to support importing data recreating their history), but after creation, the fields are read-only and are managed entirely by Sanity.